# How to remove extra newline's in C through the printf function when using multiple variables?

Tags: c, variables, printf, newline, spacing

I'm trying to print a line with multiple variables but after every variable is printed, I get a newline. Is there anyway to stop that from happening?

```
if (num == 0) {
  printf("A %s ran away, so her mom called the cops about a little %s", names[num], words[num+1]);
  printf("...and then the %s got caught.", names[num]);
}
```

Comment: That's probably because your variables have a newline character at the end.

Comment: You'll have to remove the newline character from your strings for that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the the character just before the `\0` is the newline character. Just use the following before the `printf`s to replace a newline character with the NUL-terminator:

```
names[num][strcpsn(names[num],"\n")]= '\0';
words[num+1][strcpsn(words[num+1],"\n")]= '\0';
```

The `strcpsn` function scans its first argument (which must be of type `const char*`) for the first occurrence of any of the characters that are part of its second argument (which must also be of type `const char*`), returning the number of characters of in the first string read before this first occurrence. The search includes the terminating null-characters. Therefore, the function will return the length of the first string if none of the characters of second string are found in the first one.